# Python: How to pass a variable from one python script to another

Tags: python

I know this this questions been asked before, but I can't seem to get the answers to work. I'm trying to pass the variable things from one script to another.

test.py

```
def addstuff(word):
    things = word + " good."
    return things
```

test2.py

```
from test import addstuff

addstuff("random")

stuff = things + "morethings"
```

Ive also tried   importing with

```
from test import *
```

things doesn't show up as defined in test2, How can I fix this?

Comment: `addstuff("random")` just throws the result away. You didn't assign the result to a named variable so nothing happens. It has nothing to do with the import process, it's to do with how you use the function

Comment: `things = addstuff("random")` ??

Comment: Does this help https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_modules.htm and it should be "things = addstuff("random")" in test2.py

Comment: A remotely related advice: think of your code as consisting of functions ans classes, stop thinking in terms of _"scripts"_. You can have your Python classes and functions in one file or in multiple files (btw, we call them _"modules"_), but that does not make much of a difference. There is no communication going on between files/scripts/modules - there is communication (via arguments and return values) between functions.

Comment: Yeah, another comment on that: test2.py has **no** idea what the variables named or used **within** the function in test.py are called. Nor does it care. `from test import *` only imports the names of the top level "stuff" in test.py--stuff that's not indented essentially--and it knows what those names are supposed to do/represent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `addstuff("random")` does not store the output of your `addstuff()` function from test.py into any variable, its just discarded.

The `things` in your test2.py does not mean anything to the program until its not assigned to any variable.

Here's the correct way to do it:

```
from test import addstuff

things=addstuff("random")

stuff = things + "morethings"
```

We're assigning the output of `addstuff("random")` (ie "random good.") to `things` and then adding `"morethings"`  to it.